# sparkSql no such method error

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm new to learning sparkSQL, and I'm trying to run the examples provided by the spark document, but got error like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUFi.png)

my program like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K546I.png)

what should I do.
note:I'm using the IDEA to edit my program
all of the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object SqlTest1 {

  case class Person(name: String, age:Long)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    runBasicDataFrameExample(spark)
  }

  private def runBasicDataFrameExample(spark: SparkSession)={
    val df = spark.read.json("resorces/people.json")
    df.show()
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code and not pictures of it.

Comment: import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object SqlTest1 {

  case class Person(name: String, age:Long)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    runBasicDataFrameExample(spark)
  }

  private def runBasicDataFrameExample(spark: SparkSession)={
    val df = spark.read.json("resorces/people.json")
    df.show()
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Val Conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(“appName”)

Val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(Conf).getOrCreate()

Val df = spark.read.option(“timestampFormat”,”yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ).json(path)

Answer (score 0):

it may be the scala version does not match. you can check the scala verion and spark version.